# How to not display none when checkbox already checked in filter vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make the checked tr, not to be displayed none when filtering the new input.
for example, when I tried to input a new value after checking the tr the tr will not disappear.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        // if (tbody.querySelectorAll(".doms:checked")) {
        //     tblRows[i].style.display = "";
        // } else {
        let checks = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        let far = checks.getElementsByTagName("input");
        
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">List Things</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Approved</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rock</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rock2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how to make it happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is minor change in your code. While you get your `input` you use `let far = checks.getElementsByTagName("input");` which returns `array`, so you just need to add index with it as `let far = checks.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]` so it will select relative `input`. Then add condition `if (far.checked)` will work.

Also you do not need to get `td` from `tr[i]` then `far` object. Instead you can directly use `let far = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        // below lines can be ommitted
        // let checks = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        // use tr[i] below and get input element with index [0]
        let far = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        // add below condition to hide tr only if checkbox is not checked
        if (!far.checked) {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">List Things</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Approved</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rock</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rock2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```